# How to add vertical lines in text box to separate elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS and HTML code for a simple form, however, I don't can't get vertical lines that will separate my text from my radio buttons, currently, I am just using the '|' in the body to separate it, but it doesn't look nice. How can I get the vertical lines to connect all the way from the top of the text box to the bottom?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box1 {
width: 300px;
height: 20px;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0;
float: left
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: inline;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="box1">

<form method="GET" action="." target="new">
 Up Down |
 <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
 <label for="r1">Up</label>
 <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
 <label for="r2">Down</label>
 |
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a table? And that code is not clean. Put a mockup of the page and we will help with better code

Comment: @HoussemBdr What do you need for the mockup? However, I do want to learn how to write better code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally wouldn't use table elements for layout in this case (unless I am rendering a bunch of data in a table, then it applies) because its not semantic. Instead, flexbox can handle this easily.

```
display: flex;
```

```css
.box1 form {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.col:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.col.input-control {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">

  <form method="GET" action="." target="new">
    <label class="col">Up Down</label>
    <span class="col input-control">
      <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
      <label for="r1">Up</label>
      <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
      <label for="r2">Down</label> 
    </span>
    <span class="col">
      <input type="submit" />
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay nice this seemed to work, now what if I want to add more space in between each section? For example, I want more spacing after the "Up Down" text.

Comment: Flexbox will space out its child elements according to their content width (there are other ways to control this too with justify-content for eg). So one thing you could do is add padding to the middle box. So I updated the demo for example to having padding-right: 20px on the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table and inside put the html inputs, labels.
Also you need to add CSS style to the table for a better visualization.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your radiobuttons into a div element and add borders to left and right.

https://jsfiddle.net/krbp8tx7/

```css
.box1 {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  float: left
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: inline;
}

.separateradios {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left:1px solid #000;
  border-right:1px solid #000;
  padding: 0 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box1">

    <form method="GET" action="." target="new">
      Up Down
      <div class="separateradios">
        <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
        <label for="r1">Up</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
        <label for="r2">Down</label>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```